# How to derive a noun or adective or adverb from "nya"?

Tags: terminology, translation

In Russian network jargon there is adjective "няшный" (originating from anime fandom's "nya"). It is somewhat related to "kawaii" (cute) or "nice", but not the same.

However in English any attempts to add adjective or adverb suffix to "nya" results in ugly word (unlike in Russian). How to make it properly? Alternatively, how to translate phrases with this word English in a good way (with reference to "nya" or cats and with meaning of niceness or goodness)?

The question two is how to translate it be comprehensible. The adjective seems to fit is "nice". What should be the noun? I should be like "cutie", but less diminutive.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by “ugly word,” and I do not know how “nya” is usually pronounced in English anime fandom.  But because the sound にゃ in Japanese, typically [nʲa] (which is close to the sound spelled as ня in Russian according to my very limited knowledge of Russian), does not seem to exist in English, there is no natural spelling for the word if you want to describe the pronunciation.

Comment: 1. Ugly word means it it sounds like some weird thing (not as constructed occasional word). 2. It is highly used in Russian fandom. 3. Then how to translate it?

Comment: Replacing vague phrase “ugly word” with another vague phrase “some weird thing” does not seem to help me understand what you want to say.  As I said, the sound にゃ does not seem to exist in English, and therefore there is no natural spelling for the sound if you want to describe the sound of Japanese にゃ.  The best you can do is to use whatever word is accepted in the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about one of the following? Neither seems particularly ugly.

*nyaful* - Characterized by *nya*.

*nyaesque* - Reminiscent of *nya*.

Comment: OK, how to produce a noun then (means "object or person that is 'nyaful'")?

Comment: "nyaful" seems to be more or less OK (although it will be require comments for everybody expect of Russian otakus). I was thinking about "nya-ish" or "nya-ee" (that "ugly words"), but this variant seems better.

Comment: @Anonymous Is the Russian noun a diminutive? If so, Tom Au's suggestion of _nyakin_ may work. You could also try something like _nyaling_ or _nyalet_.